# AJAX pagination with codeigniter and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

Can someone help me with a simple AJAX pagination in Codeigniter using JQuery? With the paginated list queryed from the database.
I searched the web but all the exemples are very complex...
Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: google...ajax pagination in codeigniter.. :)

Comment: I tried but they are all very complex. And i'm new to codeigniter and jquery..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

just use codeigniter pagination simple and use following code for pagination through jquery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $("#pagination-div-id a").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: $(this).attr("href"),
   data:"q=<?php echo $searchString; ?>",
   success: function(res){
      $("#containerid").html(res);
   }
   });
   return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Here pagination div id is the id of pagination container and containerid is simple the container id where you showing the result.

Comment: thanks. i didn't realise it was that simple. A would give you a vote up but i don't have enough reputation...

Comment: @beniaminSzabo i am doing that on your behalf :)

Comment: Thanks. I have enough reputation now :)

Comment: When I posted this question I was at the beginning of my programming career.

Comment: can you give me an explain to ; data:"q=<?php echo $searchString; ?>"

Comment: @Fadly Dzil :  data:"q=<?php echo $searchString; ?>" represents data which is coming from query strings (not part of pagination url).

Comment: @Fadly Dzil :  "q" is here for any query string parameter(if required). As per my requirement, i have to use pagination on search results, thatwhy i am using this "q=<?php echo $searchString; ?>" to pass the query parameter as data for further operation.

Answer (score 2):

just use codeigniter pagination library and add the following function in the library after create links function

```
function create_links_ajax()
    {
        // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
        if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0)
        {
            return '';
        }

        // Calculate the total number of pages
        $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

        // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
        if ($num_pages == 1)
        {
            return '';
        }

        // Set the base page index for starting page number
        if ($this->use_page_numbers)
        {
            $base_page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $base_page = 0;
        }

        // Determine the current page number.
        $CI =& get_instance();

        if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != $base_page)
            {
                $this->cur_page = $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);

                // Prep the current page - no funny business!
                $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != $base_page)
            {
                $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

                // Prep the current page - no funny business!
                $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
            }
        }

        // Set current page to 1 if using page numbers instead of offset
        if ($this->use_page_numbers AND $this->cur_page == 0)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $base_page;
        }

        $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;

        if ($this->num_links < 1)
        {
            show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
        }

        if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page))
        {
            $this->cur_page = $base_page;
        }

        // Is the page number beyond the result range?
        // If so we show the last page
        if ($this->use_page_numbers)
        {
            if ($this->cur_page > $num_pages)
            {
                $this->cur_page = $num_pages;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows)
            {
                $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
            }
        }

        $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;

        if ( ! $this->use_page_numbers)
        {
            $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);
        }

        // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
        // which number to start and end the digit links with
        $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
        $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

        // Is pagination being used over GET or POST?  If get, add a per_page query
        // string. If post, add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
        if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
        }
        else
        {
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
        }

        // And here we go...
        $output = '';

        // Render the "First" link
        if  ($this->first_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1))
        {
            $first_url = ($this->first_url == '') ? $this->base_url : $this->first_url;
            $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a id="'.$first_url.'" onclick="show_ajax_cards(this)" '.$this->anchor_class.'href="javascript:void(0)">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "previous" link
        if  ($this->prev_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
        {
            if ($this->use_page_numbers)
            {
                $i = $uri_page_number - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
            }

            if ($i == 0 && $this->first_url != '')
            {
                $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a id="'.$this->first_url.'" onclick="show_ajax_cards(this)"'.$this->anchor_class.'href="javascript:void(0)">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
            }
            else
            {
                $i = ($i == 0) ? '' : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
                $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a id="'.$this->base_url.$i.'" onclick="show_ajax_cards(this)"'.$this->anchor_class.'href="javascript:void(0)">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
            }

        }

        // Render the pages
        if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE)
        {
            // Write the digit links
            for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
            {
                if ($this->use_page_numbers)
                {
                    $i = $loop;
                }
                else
                {
                    $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;
                }

                if ($i >= $base_page)
                {
                    if ($this->cur_page == $loop)
                    {
                    //  $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
                    //  $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$n.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $n = ($i == $base_page) ? '' : $i;

                        if ($n == '' && $this->first_url != '')
                        {
                            $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a id="'.$this->first_url.'" onclick="show_ajax_cards(this)" '.$this->anchor_class.'href="javascript:void(0)">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $n = ($n == '') ? '' : $this->prefix.$n.$this->suffix;

                            $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a id="'.$this->base_url.$n.'" onclick="show_ajax_cards(this)"  '.$this->anchor_class.'href="javascript:void(0)">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Render the "next" link
        if ($this->next_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
        {
            if ($this->use_page_numbers)
            {
                $i = $this->cur_page + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $i = ($this->cur_page * $this->per_page);
            }

            $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<a id="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'" onclick="show_ajax_cards(this)"'.$this->anchor_class.'href="javascript:void(0)">'.$this->next_link.'</a>'.$this->next_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "Last" link
        if ($this->last_link !== FALSE AND ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages)
        {
            if ($this->use_page_numbers)
            {
                $i = $num_pages;
            }
            else
            {
                $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
            }
            $output .= $this->last_tag_open.'<a id="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'" onclick="show_ajax_cards(this)"'.$this->anchor_class.'href="javascript:void(0)"'.$this->last_link.'</a>'.$this->last_tag_close;
        }

        // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
        // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
        $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

        // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
        $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;

        return $output;
    }
```

**and in the view create a function that will look like this**

```
function show_ajax_cards(obj)
{

    var baseurl     =   obj.id;
    $.ajax({
            url:    baseurl,
            data:"baseurl="+baseurl,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(html)
                {
                   $('#cardReplace').html(html);
                }                              
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply Live click, if you are returning data from controller as follows:

```
jQuery("#pagination a").live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: jQuery(this).attr("href"),
    success: function(res){
      jQuery('#multiple_selection_data').html(res);
    }
    });
    return false;
});
```