# Can I have $.get call in $this->pagination->create_links();

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on Code igniter (new at codeigniter) and I want to do pagination on $.get.

Contoller Code is here:

```
public function get_todo($id=null)
{
     $this->_required_login();
     if($id!=null)
     {
         $result=$this->todo_model->get([
             'todo_id'=>$id,
             'user_id'=>$this->session->userdata('user_id')
         ]);

     }
     else
     {
         $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "dashboard/load_todo";   // I want here is $.get instead of a link
    //I have js files in which $.get is.
    $total= $this->todo_model->get_rows($this->session->userdata('user_id')); //Total rows
    $config["total_rows"] = $total;
    $config["per_page"] = 3; // Per Page required
    // I have no idea what it is.
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    // no idea thing ends here

    //getting results and working fine
    $data["results"] = $this->todo_model->
        fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
    // Real pain in the neck
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

     }
     $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));


}
```

Now about js file which is creating html response

```
    var load_todo = function() {
    $.get('api/get_todo',function(o){
        //api/get_todo is controller
       var output='';

       for (var i=0;i<o.results.length;i++)
       {
           output+=Template.todo(o.results[i]);  // Pagination result
       }
       output+='<p>'+o.links+'</p>'; // Pagination links
       //console.log(output);
        $("#list_todo").html(output);
    },'json');
};
```

What I want it to have o.links to have $.get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX pagination with codeigniter and jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606960/ajax-pagination-with-codeigniter-and-jquery)

Comment: Follow this tuorial: http://www.99points.info/2010/05/codeigniter-tutorials-how-to-create-ajax-pagination-using-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to return your output. In your controller method `get_todo()` edit the last line to this:

```
 return $this->output
             ->set_content_type('application/json')
             ->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: This is not the issue here :P
It is doing what I want to...
Issue here is I am doing ajax call to get list and in paging it is giving me list, I am new at web-development as well as code igniter

Comment: I dont understand what you mean: "in paging is giving me the list" Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Sorry I miss-spelled giving me link for what I am giving it in config base_url. But I want is ajax call for list to update when i click 2nd page of pagination

Comment: So your `ajax $.get` script should be called every time the user clicks on a pagination link?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606960/ajax-pagination-with-codeigniter-and-jquery

Comment: Ya that's what I want. Can u please check my code up there?

Comment: Too much to explain. You can do it by following this tutorial: http://www.99points.info/2010/05/codeigniter-tutorials-how-to-create-ajax-pagination-using-codeigniter/

Comment: CodeGodie Thats what I wanted. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of struggle and headache I finally got my answer own my own. For those who might come with same thinking about pagination as I did, if you want to do **pagination for ajax call get or post**, best way will be to change ajax_pagination library.

**ajax_pagination -> create_links() -> getAJAXlink()**

and edit its code as u want to.